# Trying to extract data from Coinbase but Python throws back error

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the bitcoin price from the coinbase website in Python but am not that familiar with HTML. When I inspect the coinbase site (https://www.coinbase.com/price/bitcoin), I get the following (this is a snippet of the whole inspection), which I think has the price to be extracted from the following:

```
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-baseline-b1fcn5pa cds-column-ci8mx7v cds-0-_1t4ck38">
   <div class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-display3-doujgnf cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-tabularNumbers-t11sqpt cds-1-_qem5ui">
      <span>£21,976.91</span>
   </div>
...
```

I tried asking chatGPT because again, I don't know HTML and it came up with this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# define the URL of the Coinbase webpage
url = 'https://www.coinbase.com/price/bitcoin'

# make a GET request to the webpage and get the HTML code
response = requests.get(url)
html_code = response.content

# create a BeautifulSoup object and parse the HTML code
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')

# find the element that contains the price data
price_element = soup.find('div', {'class': 'cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-display3-doujgnf cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-tabularNumbers-t11sqpt cds-1-_qem5ui'})

# extract the price data from the element
price_data = price_element.text.strip()

# print the price data
print(price_data)
```

It throws back the error that 'NoneType' object doesn't have an attribute 'text'. I believe this is because the soup.find() doesn't receive any input. After doing some research and some trial and error, I can't seem to fix this. Could you guys help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded with JavaScript from external URL (so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it).

You can simulate the Ajax request with following example:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://www.coinbase.com/graphql/query"
params = {
    "operationName": "useGetPriceChartDataQuery",
    "extensions": "{\"persistedQuery\":{\"version\":1,\"sha256Hash\":\"3aa896a38f822d856792f18ca18f98f49580540f517693ad4e51508c529ddb6e\"}}",
    "variables": '{"skip":false,"slug":"bitcoin","currency":"EUR"}',
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
print(data['data']['assetBySlug']['latestQuote']['price'])
```

Prints:

```
25210.325
```

---

*Note:* You can find the GraphQL URL in your browser: Open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and reload the page. This URL should be there with the request parameters and returned data.